How do I upload data to html from a database?
I have a home project, DRF is deployed in it, the database itself is on postgresql and I learned how to create a page template, BUT without data from the database. That's how I did it.:
$ mkdir static
$ vim Project1/settings.py
$ cat Project1/settings.py
...
from pathlib import Path
import os
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'portfolio',
    'ckeditor', 
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Project2')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
...
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media/"
...
$ mv Project2/css static/
$ ls static/
css
$ vim Project2/index.html
$ cat Project2/index.html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>Project2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--SECTIONS-->
    <!--CARDS-->
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="cards">
                <div class="card__content" id="">
                    <h2 class="card_hidden" onclick="card__hidden(this)">Опыт работы</h2>
                    <div style="text-align: left;">
                        <ul>            
                            <li><strong>
                            ' . $row['begin'] . ' -
                            ' . $row['finish'] . ':</strong>
                            ' . $row['place'] . ';
                            ' . $row['specialization'] . '; <strong>Дополнительная информация:</strong>
                            ' . $row['content'] . '; <strong>Достижения:</strong>
                            ' . $row['progress'] . ';
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </section> 
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
$ python manage.py runserver
$ google-chrome http://IP:8000/contents/

Yes. the site opens but without data from the database. I started to supplement the code for downloading data from the database in this way:
$ vim portfolio/models.py
$ cat portfolio/models.py
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
class Place(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Место работы")
    spec = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Должность")
    years = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Обязанности")
    progress = models.TextField(verbose_name="Достижения")
    doc=models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/%Y/%m/%d/", verbose_name="Файлы", blank=True, null=True)
    begin=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Начало работы")
    finish=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Конец работы")
    is_published=models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Публикация")
    cat=models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, verbose_name="Категории")
    ordinal = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-title"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Portfolio(models.Model):
        title = models.TextField(verbose_name="Достижение")
        description = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name="Статья")
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
        url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
        ordinal = models.IntegerField()
        def __str__(self):
                return self.title
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name="Категория")
    ordinal = models.IntegerField()
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
$ vim portfolio/views.py
$ cat portfolio/views.py
...
from django.views.generic import ListView
...
class PortfolioListView(ListView):
    model = Portfolio
$ vim Project1/urls.py
$ cat Project1/urls.py
...
from portfolio.models import Portfolio
from portfolio.views import PortfolioListView
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('contents/', views.show_contents),
    path('portfolio2/', PortfolioListView.as_view()),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
$ vim Project2/content_list.html
$ cat david138it/content_list.html
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for content in object_list %}
            <li>{{ content.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
$ google-chrome http://192.168.122.98:8000/portfolio2/
...
Internal Server Error: /portfolio2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/USER/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/USER/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/USER/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 90, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/home/USER/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 72, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "/home/USER/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(", ".join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: portfolio/portfolio_list.html
[06/Apr/2024 03:20:15] "GET /portfolio2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 83529

I ran into a problem when loading the portfolio 2 page. that is, he swears at which page from the portfolio_list, although I wrote in content_list.
I did it on the page Built-in class-based generic views
What did I do wrong???

You are using ListView
to display a list of Portfolio objects, but Django is looking for a template named portfolio/portfolio_list.html which doesn't exist.
You have following options:

Create a new template named portfolio/portfolio_list.html and use it to display the list of Portfolio objects.

Change the template_name attribute in your PortfolioListView so that it can use content_list.html template.


In your portfolio/views.py file, change the PortfolioListView as:
class PortfolioListView(ListView):
    model = Portfolio
    template_name = 'content_list.html'

Assuming:

content_list.html template is located in the correct directory (Project2/content_list.html in your case) and that it extends the correct base template (index.html in your case).


тhanks. This is what you need
